# ruby array to javascript - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass a ruby array to a js view (*js.erb* format) but it doesn't work at all.

`var array = "<%= @publishers_list %>";`

The variable *array* is just set as a *string* with all the array's values in it.

Is there a way to keep the array format ?

#### Edit

I just realized it was because  of my array format.

`[{:label => "name1", :value => value1}, {:label => "name2", :value => value2}]`

I tried to pass a simple array like:

`[1,2,3]`

and it worked fine.

The question is now: how can I pass this kind of array ? I really need to keep these hashes in it because I want to put it as a source of a jQuery autocomplete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var array = <%= escape_javascript @publisher_list.to_json %>
```

Comment: Ok I tried with "raw" instead of escape_javascript and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var array = <%= j @publishers_list.to_json %>
```

`j` is shorthand for `escape_javascript` (thanks to commenter lfx_cool).

See the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html

To clean up your view code a little, you can also turn the `@publishers_list` into `json` in your controller. That way, in your view you can just use:

```
var array = <%= j @publishers_list %>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.. when I write `console.log(array)` it displays nothing, the array is null.

Comment: From your controller do `logger.debug(@publishers_list)` and check your `development.log` to see what the output is.

Comment: `j` is not shorthand for `json_escape`, `j` is shorthand for `escape_javascript`

Answer (score 0):

simply define a array in Controller's specific action like:

```
def rails_action
  @publishers_list = []
  # write some code to insert value inside this array
  # like: 
  # @publishers.each do |publisher|
  # @publishers_list << publisher.name
  # end 
end
```

js file which is associated with this action, like: **rails_action.js.erb**

now use your code

```
var array = [];
array = "<%= @publishers_list %>";
```

Thanks.

Comment: The commented code in the controller could be changed to `@publishers_list = @publishers.map &:name`

Comment: yes, @GuilhermeBerger you are right.:). It's worse to use loop.